# Which free video editing tool can I use in windows to slice an mp4 file?

Tags: video, editing, podcasts, mp4

I would like to cut a portion of a podcast which is a mp4 file and upload to youtube. Which is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[AviDemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) is the answer. VirtualDub would be, IF you had .avi containers. VirtualDub doesn't support anything other than .avi.

Comment: Does not appear to work with .mp4

Answer (score 2):

Free video editing software:

Windows Movie Maker.
Windows MovieMaker 2 is a capable little editor and ships free with virtually all new XP computers these days package.

WAX
Wax is a high performance and flexible video compositing and special effects software. The idea for Wax is to be very general purpose and flexible in video compositing and effects, so that you can compose your dream video sequence with ease everytime.
http://www.debugmode.com/wax/

Zwei-Stein
Zwei-Stein 3.01 is a freeware non-linear, non-destructive video compositing and editing system which offers many advanced features unavailable elsewhere.
With Zwei-Stein you can edit up to 256 video, audio and still image clips, each with up to 64 effects chained serially. Cropping, panning and custom effects are easy with automatic key frames.
[http://www.thugsatbay.com/tab/?q=zweiste…](http://www.thugsatbay.com/tab/?q=zweistein)

Avedit
It is a great tool to work with .AVI files. Regardless of small executable size, this avi editor offers you unlimited power of digital video processing. Some high-tech tricks included into AVIedit allows you to perform with ease and fun the many interesting things, like video warping, color restore, noise reduction and so on...
http://www.am-soft.ru/aviedit.html

Chopper XP
Chopper XP is a tool that lets you extract a part of any DVD easily. It is a Vob cutting program with a video display and a great interface. You just need to scroll to a location and select mark in and out points. The program also lets you set any priority of extraction and displays the estimated time left for extraction.
[http://www.digital-miner.com/chopperxp.h…](http://www.digital-miner.com/chopperxp.html)

Comment: VirtualDub doesn't support mp4 containers, only avi. Virtual Edit is not free.

Comment: Windows Movie Maker is so simple for most users

Comment: Windows Movie Maker isn't compatible with .mp4

Comment: Wax doesn't seem to know about .MP4 or .WMV files

Answer (score 0):

[FormatFactory](http://www.formatoz.com/) Does a great job of cutting video/audio files up. In addition, of converting to many different video/audio formats. It is also free.

Comment: link doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question but it gave me some useful pointers so I want to share my findings:

http://www.freemake.com/

List of features relevant to original question:

- free
- cut and paste mp4 videos
- Youtube upload

Comment: I tried to install it but my firewall started to warn that setup wants to change run32.dll