# Does anyone know of a good app/tool that allows you to edit MP4 files?

Tags: video-editing, mp4

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can I merge two mp4 files without losing quality?](https://superuser.com/questions/43588/how-can-i-merge-two-mp4-files-without-losing-quality)
>   [Which free video editing tool can I use in windows to slice an mp4 file?](https://superuser.com/questions/75621/which-free-video-editing-tool-can-i-use-in-windows-to-slice-an-mp4-file)

I need to be able to increase the volume, cut out silence, add silence etc. for mp4 files. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Look at http://superuser.com/questions/75621/which-free-video-editing-tool-can-i-use-in-windows-to-slice-an-mp4-file

Answer (score 0):

I have used this and is descent for a free prgram and will do just what you want it to do.

[Avidemux - Download](http://redirectingat.com/?id=2371X601573&xs=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Favidemux.en.softonic.com%2F&sref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pchelpforum.com%2Fgeneral-software%2F66147-freeware-mp4-editor.html)

This is is a lot better but only has a 30 days trail!

[AimOne MP4 Cutter & Joiner - Free software downloads and reviews - CNET Download.com](http://redirectingat.com/?id=2371X601573&xs=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.cnet.com%2FAimOne-MP4-Cutter-amp-Joiner%2F3000-13631_4-10852877.html&sref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pchelpforum.com%2Fgeneral-software%2F66147-freeware-mp4-editor.html)